# Batch file randomly pick files that are same file names from different sub folder to one folder

Tags: batch-file, random, cmd

I need to randomly pick around 200 specific files from different sub folders to one folder. Following is the details: (`tree /F /A` result)

```
+--- source_folder
|   +--- Folder A
|   |      module_01.x
|   |      module_02.x
|   |      module_03.x
|   +--- Folder B
|   |      module_01.x
|   |      module_02.x
|   |      module_03.x
|   +--- Folder C
|   |      module_01.x
|   |      module_02.x
|   |      module_03.x
```

I want to randomly pick 3 of them for example:

```
module_01.x from folder B
module_02.x from folder C
module_03.x from folder C
```

to "dest_folder".

Following is the code I am using but only shuttles a few and it seems always picking many files from only one folder and, when it trying to copy from another folder it won't overwrite the exist files(tried the /Y but no luck).

Any suggestions? Thank you very much!

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "source_folder=test"
set "dest_folder=output"
set /a filecount=193

del "dest_folder\*.x"
pushd "source_folder"
for /r %%i in (*.x) do set /a files+=1& set "$!files!=%%~i"
popd
pushd "dest_folder"
:randomloop
set /a rd=%random%%%files+1
set "sco=!$%rd%!"
if not defined x goto :randomloop
set "$%rd%="
for %%i in ("%x%") do if exist "%%~nxi" echo "%%~nxi" already exist in %out%.& goto:randomloop
copy "%x%" /Y
set /a filecount-=1
if %filecount% gtr 0 goto:randomloop
popd

pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the way you process the files... If all subfolders have *the same files* (as you specified in "the details"), then you don't need to process *all files*, but just the files from *one subfolder* and then, randomly select the real source subfolder...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "source_folder=test"
set "dest_folder=output"

del "%dest_folder%\*.x"
pushd "%source_folder%"

rem Create the subFolder array
set "n=0"
for /D %%a in (*) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "subFolder[!n!]=%%a"
)

rem Process all files in first subfolder
pushd "%subFolder[1]%"
for %%a in (*.x) do (

   rem Select a random subfolder
   set /A "ran=!random! %% n + 1"

   rem Pick the file from such random subfolder
   for /F %%r in ("!ran!") do copy "..\!subFolder[%%r]!\%%a" "..\%dest_folder%"

)
```

**EDIT**: *Simple test added*

I tested this code in this way: I created the three folders and added four *.x files to each of them. Then, I added an `ECHO` command before the `copy` one, that is:

```
for /F %%r in ("!ran!") do ECHO copy "..\!subFolder[%%r]!\%%a" "..\%dest_folder%"
```

Finally I ran the program. This is the output:

```
copy "..\folder A\module-001.x" "..\output"
copy "..\folder C\module-002.x" "..\output"
copy "..\folder B\module-003.x" "..\output"
copy "..\folder C\module-004.x" "..\output"
```

This means that `module-001.x` file is copied from `folder A`, `module-002.x` file from `folder C`, `module-003.x` file from `folder B`, and `module-004.x` file from `folder C`.

Comment: OP wants 3 randomly selected files from randomly selected subfolders.

Comment: @ack: No. OP wants to _"pick around 200 files"_ from randomly selected subfolders. At end, destination folder must have one of _each_ of the 200 files...

Comment: `I want to randomly pick 3 of them for example:` module_01.x from folder B, module_02.x from folder C, module_03.x from folder C

Comment: @ack: Yes. The output contains one of each: module_01.x, module_02.x and module_03.x _precisely_. The _random_ part apply to the _folders_ only... It seems you and me understand different things from the same words. However, this discussion is futile until the OP clear this point.

Comment: Thank you both first and apologize for my word that's not clear enough.
@Aacini you read my mind I want that approximately 200 files to be randomly picked from different folder to the destination folder. That 200 files got the same file name but in different location like : ___Folder 1 contain "module-001.x to module-200.x", _____Folder 2 contain "module-001.x to module-200.x", ___Folder 3 contain module-001.x to module-200.x. __All I want is a batch cmd which can randomly picking "module-001.x to module-200.x" from either Folder1, Folder2 or Folder3 to the destination folder. Thank you

Comment: @Aacini appreciate your help but the script you provided above seems picking all the files from only one sub folder, am I doing something wrong? thanks

Comment: You can not say that the code _seems_ not working correctly. You _must_ do a test to prove that, specially when the test is very simple... **`:(`** See my edit. @ack

Comment: @Aacini Really sorry for my words and hugely appreciate for your help. I created a folder which include these things: a .bat file, "dest_folder", "source_folder". Then the "source_folder" containing "folder A", "folder B", "folder C", each of them have 4 .x files. When I run the .bat it said "The system cannot find the file specified" and "the system cannot find the path specified" I know this is a stupid question but I just can't figure out which part going wrong I tried many times to modify the script or the folder location but the problem still exists. Thank you indeed.

Comment: In your code _you_ specified that the source_folder is called `test` and the dest_folder is called `output`. You may either change these folder names in the disk _OR_ change all `%dest_folder%` and `%source_folder%` in the program by `dest_folder` and `source_folder` (in this case the first two `set` commands are useless and may be removed). You must also know that the program _must_ be executed from a `cmd.exe` window; it does _not_ work if you double-click it from the explorer...

Comment: @Aacini Thank you very much! :)  I run the cmd.exe using admin permissoin and use  `cd` to locate my .bat file and run the .bat it said 4 files have been copied to the **output** just like what you have mentioned above but there have nothing in the output folder. Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: The `ECHO` command just _display_ the line after it. To _copy_ the files, just remove the `ECHO` part or, better yet, add another line and enclose both in parentheses so the command be displayed _and_ executed...

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, after I added `"..\"`  before the **output** and it works! The output folder should not be the same location with the sub folders. This is the line  `"for /F %%r in ("!ran!") do copy "..\!subFolder[%%r]!\%%a" "..\../output"`  cheers :)